# How to display only the maid that is available with the date? SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a Maid table which store the maid details and Appointment table that store the appointment details such as every appointment is assigned to which maid, so the appointment table holding the maid id. How to display only the maid which is not yet assigned to any job (available maid) and the date that the maid is available?

Table Maid

[image]

Table Appointment

[image]

What I have done.

```
SELECT Maid_ID FROM Maid
EXCEPT
SELECT WO_MaidName FROM Appointments
```

Given a user input of `2019-06-03`, I want this result:

```
Maid_ID    Available Date
--------------------------
   2        2019-06-03
   3        2019-06-03
   5        2019-06-03
```

Comment: You have an error ? Except is good here, I don't see what can be the error.

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta , no error, but the result is not meet to my need.  I want it to display the maid together with the date that the maid is free or available. My previous query is just display the maid id which is not yet assign to the appointment.

Comment: So what date is maid 2 available? every date?

Comment: Why the column `Maid_Age` is an `N/VARCHAR` data type instead of `INT`?

Comment: Let me give the scenario. In table Appointment, on 3 Jun, the maid with id 1 and 4 have been assigned to an appointment. Maid with id 2,3 and 5 is free on 3 Jun. So now I want to display the maid 2, 3 and 5 together with the date 3 Jun. How can I do this?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid , yes

Comment: Where do you get 3rd June from?

Comment: Is it an input parameter?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid User select the appointment date

Comment: I am going to edit your question and put info that would have helped to have been earlier: example outcome, input parameter. I really don't see the relevance of just returning the date that you already entered.

Comment: @testtest Shouldn't the `Appointment` table have a start and end date time, or is there a fixed amount of time for each appointment ?

Comment: @MJoy yes, it's fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, try this, please:

```
-- Create a Temporary table for keep Maid_Id and AppointmentDateTime
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
    (
        Maid_Id INT,
        AppointmentDateTime DATETIME
    )


-- Select all AppointmentDateTime are present in Appointment
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct Appointment.AppointmentDateTime FROM Appointment; 


-- Iterate them to insert them into the temporary table
DECLARE @date datetime;
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @date;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO #TEMP (Maid_Id, AppointmentDateTime)
        SELECT M.Maid_Id, @date FROM Maid M
        WHERE M.Maid_Id NOT IN (
            SELECT a.Maid_Id FROM Appointment a
            WHERE A.AppointmentDateTime = @date
        )

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @date;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;


-- Create another temporary table to keep all the dates we need
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2019-05-10',
        @MaxDate DATE = '2019-07-24';
CREATE TABLE #DATES 
    (
        [DATE] DATETIME
    )


-- Create a range of dates that we need and insert them in the temporary table. It can cover a wide range of dates like 2000-01-01 to Now
INSERT INTO #DATES
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.OBJECT_ID) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    SYS.ALL_OBJECTS A
CROSS JOIN SYS.ALL_OBJECTS B;


-- Union all the data
SELECT M.Maid_Id, M.Maid_Name, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), T.AppointmentDateTime, 120) [date] FROM #TEMP T
INNER JOIN Maid M ON T.Maid_Id = M.Maid_Id
UNION
SELECT null, 'All People Are Free', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [DATE], 120) FROM #DATES
ORDER BY [date]


DROP TABLE #TEMP
DROP TABLE #DATES
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT Maid_ID 
FROM Maid LEFT JOIN Appointments
    ON Maid.Maid_ID = Appointments.WO_MaidName
WHERE Appointments.WO_MaidName IS NULL
```

This query returns all rows from Maid table without any rows associated in Appointments table.

```
SELECT Maid_ID
FROM Maid
WHERE Maid_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT WO_MaidName
    FROM Appointments
    WHERE Appointment_DateTime BETWEEN '20190603' AND '20190604')
```

This second query returns all Maid rows with no Appointments between the dates in the where clause.

Comment: I want to also display the date that the maid is available

Comment: @testtest where are the availability dates?

Comment: @testtest On which table is the date?

Comment: Let me give the scenario. In table Appointment, on 3 Jun, the maid with id 1 and 4 have been assigned to an appointment. Maid with id 2,3 and 5 is free on 3 Jun. So now I want to display the maid 2, 3 and 5 together with the date 3 Jun. How can I do this?

Comment: @testtest I have edited the answer with a new query, is that what you want?

Comment: @FábioNascimento my scenario is just an example for one date. I want it to display for every date. Example 11 Jun is assigned to maid 4, so maid 1, 2, 3, 5 is free on 11 Jun.   20 Jun is assigned to maid 4, so maid 1, 2, 3, 5 is free on 20 Jun.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not optimized, but it works.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
    (
        Maid_Id INT,
        AppointmentDateTime DATETIME
    )

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct Appointment.AppointmentDateTime FROM Appointment; 
DECLARE @date datetime;
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @date;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO #TEMP (Maid_Id, AppointmentDateTime)
        SELECT M.Maid_Id, @date FROM Maid M
        WHERE M.Maid_Id NOT IN (
            SELECT a.Maid_Id FROM Appointment a
            WHERE A.AppointmentDateTime = @date
        )

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @date;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

SELECT T.Maid_Id, M.Maid_Name, T.AppointmentDateTime FROM #TEMP T
INNER JOIN Maid M ON T.Maid_Id = M.Maid_Id
ORDER BY AppointmentDateTime

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your query, I get the result not the same as yours because it displayed the time also. I want to display exactly like yours.

Comment: What was the problem? Please send your `Table Schema` and your `Data` and also your result. About my query, first of all, it makes a temporary table. Second, it retrieves all dates `SELECT distinct Appointment.AppointmentDateTime FROM Appointment'. Then iterate them(Maid_Id and AppointmentDate) with `Cursor` and insert them into the temp table. In the end, join the temp table with the Maid. table

Comment: The query above is only showing the date which already in the table appointment. How to make a query to display also the date that is not in the table?

Comment: Eg. 13 Jun will display all maid 1,2,3,4 and 5 since no one is assigned to 13 Jun appointment

Comment: Which dates should display? For example from the minimum date from today? or something else?

Comment: I want to display for every date

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a specific date and call it on each date what you want.
First, add a `Table-valued Function` in `SqlServer` like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction]
(   
    @date datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT M.Maid_Id FROM Maid M
            WHERE M.Maid_Id NOT IN (
                SELECT a.Maid_Id FROM Appointment a
                WHERE A.AppointmentDateTime = @date
            )
)
```

And then call it this way:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2019-05-15 00:00:00.000'; // Put the date you want
SELECT m.Maid_Id, m.Maid_Name, @Date FROM Maid M
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MyFunction](@Date) F ON M.Maid_Id = F.Maid_Id
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want a specific date. I want it to display all date